# OR statement returning wrong number

Tags: php

If i put 1 or 2 into this it will return 4. Why is this?I'm more used to python stuff so sorry if this is rather basic.

```
e = 1;
f=0;

if(e==1){f=1;}
if(e==2){f=2;}
if(e== 3 or 4){f=4;}
echo f;
```

Comment: `if(e== 3 or e == 4){f=4;}` You also need to us ethe right variable syntax...

Comment: Your or statement doesn't work like you think it does. What it basically comes down to is: `(e== 3) or (4)` now no matter what `e` is or if `e==3` evaluates to true, `4` always evaluates to true and thus therefore enters the if statement. Also you have all single if statements.

Comment: Turn on error reporting and get ready for a screen full of bleh! Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your page.

Comment: Learn about [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: @JohnConde: what variables? All I see is a bunch of undefined constants that php will convert into strings, so it's all `'e' == 1`, `'e' == 2`, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing :

```
if(e== 3 or 4){f=4;}
```

with

```
if(e == 3 or e == 4){ f=4; }
```

The value 4 is considered to be `TRUE` by the language.  In your code, `1 == 3` is `FALSE`, so the if statement is looking at `(FALSE or TRUE)` which is equals `TRUE`, so `f` is set to 4.

Have a look at this link re:  [PHP Booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: _"In your code, 3 == 3 is FALSE"_ in what world??? Don't you mean `e == 3` (or even `1 == 3` / `2 == 3`)?

Comment: Corrected.  e is 1, not 3.

Answer (score 1):

For your `or` statement, this is what you want:

```
if ( ($e == 3) || ($e == 4) ) {
    $f=4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), you'll see that pretty much everything is equals to `true` in php (*except for those values stated in that same page*). So what you really have is something like this:

```
if($e==3 or true)
```

And since `anything or true` is always `true`, you get that (weird, but not unexpected) result.

---

In case you want to check if `$e` is equals to `3` or `4`, do it like so:

```
if($e==3 || $e==4){
```

---

Note that since these are not `if..else` statements, every condition is being checked. Take a look at the expanded version:

```
if($e==1){
    $f=1;
}
if($e==2){
    $f=2;
}
if($e==3 or 4){
    $f=4;
}
```

This /\ is different from

```
if($e==1){
    $f=1;
}elseif($e==2){
    $f=2;
}elseif($e==3 or 4){
    $f=4;
}
```

Since the latter only checks every condition in case none of the previous fit.

---

Another side note.. since you like python, that code could be converted into this single line:

```
$f = ($e==3 || $e==4) ? 4 : $e;
```

Answer (score 0):

The next statement is always going to be true

```
if(e== 3 or 4)
```