# PHP if statement OR not working

Tags: php

Afternoon all, I am trying to optimize and reduce my code. I cant get my head around the following:

This code...

```
$asset_array = array('steel', 'copper', 'gold', 'silver');
foreach ($asset_array as $asset){
    $symbol = "";
    if ($asset == "gold"){
        $symbol = "£";  
    }
    if ($asset == "silver"){
        $symbol = "£";  
    }
    echo $asset . $symbol . "<br />";
}
```

echo's this...

```
steel
copper
gold£
silver£
```

But this code...

```
$asset_array = array('steel', 'copper', 'gold', 'silver');
foreach ($asset_array as $asset){
    $symbol = "";
    if ($asset == "gold" || "silver"){
        $symbol = "£";  
    }
    echo $asset . $symbol . "<br />";
}
```

echo's this...

```
steel£
copper£
gold£
silver£
```

Please could somebody explain what is going on? The 1st result is what I am actually trying to achieve I was just trying to do it with less code.

Many Thanks

Comment: 16 hours earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38316392/3933332

Comment: try this ($asset == "gold" || $asset ==  "silver")

Comment: you need to learn about PHP [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), and the order-of-execution that comes from that precedence.

Comment: it will be true because you compare $asset with logic statement which is TRUE, $asset is casted to boolean because operator is "==" and  true == true so condition works. 

correct way is the one @DhavalDave wrote and even better if you use === operator intead of ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the variable on both sides:

```
if ($asset == "gold" || $asset ==  "silver"){
```

Otherwise, it reads as "If asset equals silver, or if this string which always is true because it's not 0/false/null"